# Series of product of divergent sequence with sequence whose liminf is positive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a **decreasing** sequence $(\gamma_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$\sum_n \gamma_n = +\infty$$

Suppose now that for some outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ we have that after some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ the $\liminf$ of the negative of the inner product between the sequences of random vectors $T_n$ and $h(\theta_n(\omega))$ is positive, i.e.
$$\liminf\quad -T_n(\omega)^Th(\theta_n(\omega)) >0 \qquad n>N$$

How can I show this?

$$\sum_n -\gamma_{n+1}T_n^T(\omega)h(\theta_n(\omega)) = +\infty$$

I feel like this is a basic result in analysis but cannot work it out.

Comment: The $\lim \cdot \inf$ is, by definition, the limit of infima, thus the inner product will be at least some $\alpha > 0$ for all large $N.$ Q.E.D.

(Also, your signs are odd, I believe the series diverges to $-\infty.$)

Comment: @WillM. thank you for your comment! I understand that their inner product (and the limit of their inner product) will be larger than $0$, but I'm not sure I understand why then this means that the series diverges

Comment: Not larger than zero, the infima are larger than some positive number! (This is stronger of what you claim.)

Comment: Basically my question could be asked as follows: I have a series $\sum_n a_n = +\infty$ and a sequence $b_n$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n > 0$. How do I show that $\sum_n a_n b_n$ diverges?

Comment: @WillM. Right! I didn't think about that. Still, could you please help me with my last comment?

Comment: $b_n \geq \alpha,$ thus $\sum a_n b_n \geq \alpha \sum a_n.$

Comment: @WillM. wow that detail makes the whole difference! Thank you!

Comment: @WillM. do you mind writing up an answer with a few details? I'll accept it

Comment: I ask for a solution cause I'm not 100% confident with my analysis skills and I'm not 100% sure of why it should be larger than a constant $\alpha$ larger than $0$